# How do I add default JVM arguments with Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, jar, build.gradle, jvm-arguments

I need to add default JVM options to my jar, when build with Gradle.
From the documentation I got that I have to set:

```
applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ["-Djavafx.embed.singleThread=true"]
```

I have not much experience with Gradle and the developer that wrote the build.gradle file wrote it different from what most websites give as examples.

Here is the build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

version = '0.1'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
    compile 'placeholder'
}

task release(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes("Implementation-Title": "placeholder",
                "Implementation-Version": version,
                'Main-Class': 'placeholder.Application')
    }
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }

    with jar
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.2.1'
}
```

I don't know where to put the arguments. I tried putting them in different locations, but I always get:

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'placeholder'.
> No such property: applicationDefaultJvmArgs for class: org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar_Decorated
```

Much Thanks,
Jhonny

Comment: When do you need to add the JVM parameter? Could you just set the system variable in the static of initialization of your main class?

Comment: I need to add the parameter at compile time, so the user doesn't have to add it manual when he is starting his .jar

Comment: You can do something like `System.setproperty("javafx.embed.singleThread", "true") ` in code but you will to make sure that this statement gets executed before the system property gets accessed somewhere.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

From the top of my head I can think of 2 options:

**Option1: Do what @Ethan said, it'll likely work:**

```
package placeholder;

//your imports

public class Application{
  static {
      System.getProperties().set("javafx.embed.singleThread", "true");  
  }
  // your code
  public static void main(String... args){
    //your code
  }
}
```

**Option 2: Use the application plugin + default jvm values**

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'application'
//your code
applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ["-Djavafx.embed.singleThread=true"]
```

Now you can run your code 2 ways:

From gradle

```
$gradle run
```

From distribution(script). from the generated script that the application plugin will provide:

```
$gradle clean build distZip
```

Then gradle will generate a zip file somewhere under `${your.projectdir}/build`. Find the zip then unzip it and under `/bin` you'll find a `${yourproject}.bat` and `${yourproject}` executables. One is for Linux/mac/unix (`${yourproject}`) the other one is for windows (`${yourproject.bat}`)

**Option 3 (Android Developer): Use gradle.properties to set jvm argument**

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.

# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.

# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html

# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
# Default value: -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
# org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 

# You can setup or customize it according to your needs and combined with the above default value.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Djavafx.embed.singleThread=true
```

For more info on how to use gradle build environment on [docs.gradle.org](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html)

Comment: Thank you, the second option worked. The first option looked like it worked, but only in IntelliJ. The jar seems to have a different execution order, so it didn't work there.

Comment: @portenez, I think option 3 is for the JVM that is running gradle

Answer (score 4):

applicationDefaultJvmArgs is provided by the [`Application`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) plugin. So if you apply that plugin, the error would probably go away, and you should be able to execute the program by issuing `gradle run` once you set the mainClassName property to the fully qualified class name, the main method of which you want to invoke.

Comment: Ok, after looking deeper into this, the Application plugin only enables the jvm parameters to be executed with gradle run. But I need them to be executed by the .jar, when the consumer wants to start the application.

Answer (score 3):

Using a local gradlew is the easiest.
Just append to DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS.

```
# Add default JVM options here. You can also use JAVA_OPTS and GRADLE_OPTS to pass JVM options to this script.
DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS='"-Xmx64m" "-Xms64m" "-XX:+AllowRedefinitionToAddDeleteMethods"'
```

Comment: best so far! many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can use command-line with gradle task：

```
class AppRun extends JavaExec {
    private boolean withDebug

    @Option(option = "with-debug", description = "enable debug for the process. ")
    public void setDebugMode(boolean debug) {
        this.withDebug = debug
    }

    public boolean getDebugMode() {
        return this.withDebug
    }
}

task run(type: AppRun) {
}
```

then run task with options

> gradle run --with-debug

Answer (score -2):

set this to Your java main Class.

```
static {
    System.setProperty("nashorn.args", "--no-deprecation-warning");
}
```