# Error: Out of memory: Java heap space. Configure Gradle memory settings using '-Xmx' JVM option

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle

when in create new project in android studio i get this error

> "Out of memory: Java heap space. Configure Gradle memory settings
> using '-Xmx' JVM option (e.g. '-Xmx2048m'.)
>
> Please fix the project's Gradle settings.

Comment: Have you tried following the instructions and editing the `gradle.properties` file and either adding/updating the `org.gradle.jvmargs` line with a memory size?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35244961/how-do-i-add-default-jvm-arguments-with-gradle

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

In my case Invalidate cache and restart the android studio(which is automatically restarted) then an error will go after restarting the android studio

File-> Invalidate cache/restart-> Invalidate and restart

[image]

then
[image]

I hope you will find the answer...
please share your feedback